# WYSIWYG with absolute element positioning

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Does anyone know a javascript WYSIWYG (free or paid) that allows for absolute positioning of text and images inside of it?

Comment: They all do if you open the HTML view - you can do whatever you want manually.

Comment: Most editors do not support such a 'drag and drop' functionality. Diodeus is right. The best editors I came across are the CKEditor and the TinyMCE (I prefer CKEditor).

Comment: you ever find a good one free or paid with the drag and drop functionality? currently looking for the same, and ckeditor's not cutting it

Answer (score 4):

Hotglue is free, OpenSource, and allows complete absolute positioning, it can create entire pages, has support for multiple users, and stores HTML docs in flat-files and uses AJAX to keep the pages saved while editing, it even has a history and you can compare/restore previous versions.

http://hotglue.org/

I replaced the icon pictures though, as they aren't very similar to current designs out there, and you can disable things you don't need like embedding videos/etc.